# Статическая и нерасширяемая среда распределения классов

Tags: java, интерфейс

[Читаю](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) (стр 245)

> Интерфейсы предназначены для поддержки динамического разрешения вызовов
>   методов во время выполнения. Как правило, для нормального выполнения
>   вызова метода из одного класса в другом оба класса должны присутствовать во время
>   компиляции, чтобы компилятор `Java` мог проверить совместимость сигнатур
>   методов. **Само по себе это требование создает статическую и нерасширяемую среду
>   распределения классов.** **В такой системе функциональные возможности неизбежно
>   передаются вверх по иерархии классов, в результате чего механизмы будут
>   становиться доступными все большему количеству подклассов.** Интерфейсы предназначены
>   для предотвращения этой проблемы. Они изолируют определение метода
>   или набора методов от иерархии наследования. А поскольку иерархия интерфейсов
>   не совпадает с иерархией классов, то классы, никак не связанные между
>   собой иерархически , могут реализовать один и тот же интерфейс. Именно в этом
>   возможности интерфейсов проявляются наиболее полно.

Не совсем понятны следующие утверждения:

1. Само по себе это требование создает статическую и нерасширяемую среду распределения классов.
2. В такой системе функциональные возможности неизбежно передаются вверх по иерархии классов, в результате чего механизмы будут становиться доступными все большему количеству подклассов.

Интуитивно догадываюсь о сути, но внутренне сформулировать понимание для себя не удается.

Comment: Какую то вы жесть читаете. Как будто бюрократ 80-го уровня писал.

Answer (score 0):

2. Есть один класс. Есть его наследник. Есть наследник наследника и так далее. В итоге нижестоящие классы обрастают всеми методами своих родителей.